# Memory Model and ThreadPool

Tags: c#, concurrency, task, volatile, memory-model

I have one class NonVolatileTest :

```
public class NonVolatileTest 
{
    public bool _loop = true;
}
```

and I have two examples of code:

1:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NonVolatileTest t = new NonVolatileTest();

    Task.Run(() => { t._loop = false; });

    while (t._loop) ;
    Console.WriteLine("terminated");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

2:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NonVolatileTest t = new NonVolatileTest();

    Task.Run(() => { t._loop = false; });

    Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (t._loop) ;
            Console.WriteLine("terminated");
        });

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In the first example all works as expected and 'while' cycle is never terminated, but in the second example all works allegedly '_loop' field is volatile.

Why?

PS. 
VS 2013, .NET 4.5, x64 
Release mode & Ctrl + F5

Hypothesis:

This 'bug' may be related to the TaskScheduler. I think, before JIT puts second task for compilation and running, the first task has been finished, so JIT takes the changed value.

Comment: The fact that field is not marked as volatile doesn't mean the compiler/optimizer/jitter *won't* re-read it. It may also be as simple as the fact that in the first example the code manages to race to the reading of the boolean flag before the task has managed to set it to false, but in the second case the 2nd task also has overhead in starting to run which means the first task has managed to set the boolean to false first. Try adding a sleep to the start of the first task and re-test.

Comment: Also, the first code is obviously wrong. First you never set `loop` to true, and it is named `loop` in one place, and `_loop` in the other. Can you please post the correct code?

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen, I fix it with delay:
Thread.Sleep(1000) 
before the starting second task.

Comment: This 'bug' may be related to the TaskScheduler. 
I think, before JIT puts second task for compilation and running, the first task has been finished, so JIT takes the changed value.

Comment: If you "solved" your problem either post a answer explaining how it was solved and accept it once the two day limit has  passed or delete the question, do not just edit in a "solved" section in to your question.

Comment: You've written code that is allowed to behave *however it wants* because you're relying on behaviors that are guaranteeing nothing.  That behavior that's allowed to do anything doesn't always do the same thing is *entirely expected*.  It's like saying that a coin flip sometimes lands on heads and sometimes lands on tails.

Comment: **DETERMINISTIC CHAOS**, predictions about results are limited. This question and its code should be marked as **VERY BAD IDEA**

Answer (score 2):

According to the [C# 5 specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) (and the same passage can be found in the annotated C# 4 specification), under section 10.5.3 - Volatile Fields, this is stated:

> When a field-declaration includes a volatile modifier, the fields introduced by that declaration are volatile fields. 
>   **For non-volatile fields, optimization techniques that reorder instructions can lead to unexpected and unpredictable results in multi-threaded programs that access fields without synchronization** such as that provided by the lock-statement (§8.12). These optimizations can be performed by the compiler, by the run-time system, or by hardware. For volatile fields, such reordering optimizations are restricted:

*(my emphasis)*

So this is documented to be unpredictable (aka out of your control).

The fact that the two pieces of code behaves different can come down to the difference between hoisting the code out to a method on the generated object (for the closure) and not hoisting it.

---

My psychic code reading eyes tells me that this is what is probably happening in the first case:

1. The task is spun up, but this has overhead before the actual code in the delegate is called
2. Before the delegate has been called, the main program continues and manages to start the loop, doing a single read of the control variable, and keep reusing its cached copy.
3. The delegate is eventually executed, but this has no impact on the loop since it has already read the variable once and has no inclination to do it again.

In the second case, the above scenario is changed slightly by the fact that the first scenario effectively does "read of variable through some object reference" and the second scenario effectively does "read of variable through `this` reference", which *may* impose differences.

But the real answer here is that you're prone to the optimizer and have written unpredictable code.

Don't be alarmed that the result is also unpredictable.

Tiny seemingly unrelated changes to the code can make the optimizer do things differently.

Comment: @usr Either program is entirely within their rights to behave in either way.  There is no guarantee of *either* program producing any specific result.  That the result is different for different programs *that are entirely within their rights to do whatever they want* is *entirely* expected.

Comment: @usr What's strange about two programs that are each allowed to do *whatever the heck they want* not doing exactly the same thing?  The expectation that they must do exactly the same thing is simply a baseless assumption.  *There is nothing strange going on here*.

Answer (score -1):

There is an article about Memory Model: http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/

There is the table in the part "Memory model and .NET operations"  :
"table of how various .NET operations interact with the imaginary thread cache."

As I saw, ordinary reading doesn't refresh the thread cache.
And I think it means that second task was started after the first task has been finished, because second thread has read 'false' value.

Next code shows  result "terminated: 0", as expected in this case.

This part of code is equal 2nd example:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NonVolatileTest t = new NonVolatileTest();

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var i = 0;
        while (t._loop)
        {
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("terminated: {0}", i);
    });
    //add delay here
    Task.Run(() => { t._loop = false; });

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This is confirmed by the fact if before starting of the second Task has been added Thread.Sleep(1000) delay, the second task will read the not changed value (true), because the first task is not finished yet, and we have the same behavior as in the 1st example.